# Prefect trigger docker image

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances, prefect

So I have a docker image on Azure container instance which I can start manually on azure portal. Now I want to run this image using prefect. Is there any way to create a deployment where it just runs that image on Azure Container Instance. When I try to do this most tutorial want to run a flow inside a docker image but I dont want anything with prefect inside the image itself I just want prefect as the trigger to run this image. All help is greatly appreciated! If any more information is needed please ask in the comments and will try to give more information!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to kick off a run of an image on Azure Container Instance using Azure's Management API for Python. The Azure docs have an example of the steps here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/container-instance?view=azure-python